# How to use a value of a specific cell from a named range?

Tags: excel, vba, range, named

I have a series of tables that all have names (i.e. they are named ranges).  These tables add a series of numbers together and then provide a total in the very bottom right hand cell of the rectangular table.  These tables are pasted into the document in different locations depending on where the user puts them.

So the question is, how do I, knowing the Name of each of these tables, extract the value of the totals cell in the bottom right hand corner of these tables and then add them together into a cell?

Comment: could you just add all the tables instead of using the totals cells `=sum(named_range1,named_range2)`

Comment: the table calculates prices based on hours entered into the same table so that kinda wont work :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of any information about what you have tried already something like this should work:

```
Dim sumTotal as Integer
Dim NamedRange as Range
Set NamedRange = ActiveSheet.Range("NameOfRange")

'Find the Bottom Right Corner
sumTotal = sumTotal + NamedRange.Cells(1, 1).Offset(NamedRange.Rows.Count - 1, NamedRange.Columns.Count - 1).Value

'do this for each NamedRange
```

Comment: can the "NameOfRange" be a variable? because I have no idea how many tables will be pasted into this document.  I have a VBA code that creates a list of the table names inserted into the document, I want to use the code you just gave me using a loop to loop through the names to add them all together

Answer (score 1):

If tables as in Insert > Tables - Table then with a formula such as:

```
=Table1[[#Totals],[sum]]+Table2[[#Totals],[sum]]+Table3[[#Totals],[sum]]
```

[image: SO20555364 example]

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but no it is not Inserted tables, just ones I have drawn up myself